# Concatenate multiple lines into "special-character"-delimited string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Say I have these Bash commands:

```
$ sha="$(git log --all --format=format:%H -n 1 -- .npp.json)"
$ git branch  --contains "$sha" | tr -d " *"
```

right now that might log something like:

```
master
dev
remotes/origin/foo
```

my question is - is there some Bash utility that can concatenate all the output for me, so that I get something like this:

```
master:dev:remotes/origin/foo
```

the utility might look like:

```
$ git branch  --contains "$sha" | tr -d " *" | concat ":"
```

of course the final value would need to be echoed, so it might look like:

```
$ result="$(git branch  --contains "$sha" | tr -d " *" | concat ":")"
$ echo "$result"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking how to change

```
master
dev
remotes/origin/foo
```

to

```
master:dev:remotes/origin/foo
```

then `tr '\n' :` would be the classical UNIXy way to do it.

As for trimming a possible final newline, you could save the output to a variable first via `$()` and the `$()` will remove it, or you can do the substitution, save the result in a variable and then do `variable=${variable%:}` to trim it the final colon. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file for more options.)

Comment: thanks, I improved the title of the OP (I think), looks like your solution works

Comment: what about trimming any extra whitespace? I like to be very sure lulz

Comment: @AlexanderMills Mentioned two ways you can get rid of it.

Comment: If you're going to do a command substitution + parameter substitution, you could consider using parameter substitution in place of `tr` to do the replacement e.g. `var=$(git branch . . . ) ; var="${var//$'\n'/:}"`

Comment: @steeldriver Good point. There's definitely many other ways to do this. I just generally try to avoid non-POSIX stuff in shell answers (the feature you mention is a bashism/kshism).

Answer (score 1):

For my use case, splitting on whitespace characters will work, since git branches cannot contain whitespace chars.

So I can do this:

```
git branch  --contains "$sha" | tr -d " *" | xargs
```

but for a generic solution, it would help to be able to control what the delimiting character was, so I don't really consider xargs used above, to be a good generic solution.

Comment: ... in that case you could replace `xargs` by `paste -sd :` I think

Comment: oh got it, how does that compare with the `tr` solution by @PSkocik